# Keeping only unique values when using join merge rule with Spatial Join and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, field-mapping

As part of a longer process, I have two point layers that I am spatially joining together. One point layer has one point per location.  The other point layer has multiple points at the same locations. I want to spatially join them together using the Join merge rule to get all of the attribute values for each point into each field, however, I only want unique values. For example, if there are three points at one location that have the values GW, SW, and GW for a field called type, I want the concatenation to only include one GW value so the field would only have two values instead of three.

As it is, I might get something like GW_GW instead of GW. "_" is my delimiter. Or maybe GW_SW_GW when what I would want would be GW_SW.

I'm not sure how to write that code.

I seek any hints at how to write that code or otherwise accomplish what I am trying to do. I've included a section of the attribute table and highlighted the cells that should only have one value.  I have approximately 10 fields that have similar issues and thousands of rows so this isn't something that can be done manually. The code I posted has 3 fields.

How can I adjust this code to check for values before it appends the next one?

```
    import arcpy
    all_shp_4_ = "C:\\path\\all.shp" 
    singledissolved_shp = "C:\\path\singledissolved.shp"
   
 # Generate a field mappings object and add the two join layers
    fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
    fieldmappings.addTable(singledissolved_shp)
    fieldmappings.addTable(all_shp_4_)


    #get field names  from the join features

    fnames = arcpy.ListFields(all_shp_4_)

    for field in fnames:
        if field.name == "vul":
            fidx = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name)
            fmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(fidx)

            # Set the merge rule to join
            fmap.mergeRule = "join"
            fmap.joinDelimiter = "_"

            fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(fidx, fmap)

        if field.name == "gw_sw":
            fidx = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name)
            fmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(fidx)

            # Set the merge rule to join
            fmap.mergeRule = "join"
            fmap.joinDelimiter = "_"

            fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(fidx, fmap)

        if field.name == "names":
            fidx = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex(field.name)
            fmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(fidx)

            # Set the merge rule to join
            fmap.mergeRule = "join"
            fmap.joinDelimiter = "_"

            fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(fidx, fmap)




    join_shp = "C:\\path\\join.shp"

    arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(singledissolved_shp, all_shp_4_, join_shp, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", fieldmappings)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider delete identical tool.

Comment: The Delete Identical tool won't work because there aren't any identical records.  I don't want to delete any records.  I just don't want duplicate values concatenated.  For example Assume there were three points at the same location and the first point has a value of  GW in the 1st field and jar in the second field. The second point has a value of GW in the first field but bucket in the second field and the third point has the values SW and jar.  the new field values for that point would be  GW_SW and jar_bucket.  I want all of the values for all of the points, but not duplicate values.

Comment: What are the variables `singledissolved_shp` and `all_shp_4_` at the start of the code you have presented set to?  For advice on writing code snippets to present here please see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers.

Comment: You had a tag for ModelBuilder but the body of your question makes no mention of how that is relevant to your question so I removed it.

Comment: It may or may not make any difference but are you trying to do this using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I am working in ArcGIS Pro. I edited the script to include the path to the singledissolved_shp and the all_shp_4_ shapefiles.  This code runs, but it does not do what I want it to.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Pro